# At API I can't access FormData object that I have created At vue js

Tags: api, vuejs2, laravel-8, form-data

If i send and image only i can access it, but problem is that i need to send some titles, sub titles and text.

My form tag:

```
<form @submit.prevent="handleFormSubmit" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

My blog data looks like this:

```
   blog:{
                postTitle: '',
                sectionTitles:[
                    {
                        sectionTId: 0,
                        title: ''   ,
                        belongsTo: '' 
                    },
                    
                ],
                images: [
                    {
                        // imageId: 0,
                        // belongsTo:''
                    }

                ],
                textareas: [
                    {
                        textareaId:0,
                        text: '',
                        belongsTo:''
                    },

                ]

            },
```

here is my submit:

```
async handleFormSubmit(){
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('blog',this.blog)
    await this.setCreatePost(data)
},
```

At Laravel I just return request:

```
return $request['blog'];
```

And I get:

```
data: "[object Object]"
```

Comment: `data.append('blog',JSON.stringify(this.blog))`

Comment: can you answer so i can fill the answer plz, and thanks, that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.append('blog',JSON.stringify(this.blog))
```